# Como editar una imagen en GRAILS Groovy cargada en la base de datos

Tags: grails, groovy

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente.
Genero un Domain fotos:

```
class Foto {

byte[] foto
String nombreFoto

  static constraints = {
        foto size: 0..1000000000
    }
}
```

Cuando auto genero los controller y vistas con grails, y levanto la app.
Despues de guardar una imagen, la misma realizar el metodo save() sin problemas.

Mi inconveniente esta en cuando solicito editar esa entrada, y selecciono una nueva foto.
Al darle al boton "EDIT", me lleva a una vista que no existe y no me genera ningun error de ningun tipo, eso si, la imagen ni siquiera los demas atributos son actualizados.

el error es un 405.

No he modificado ningun metodo, ni ninguna vista, dejando todo por defecto tal cual lo realiza grails con el  generate-all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución al problema es realizar un `POST` en vez de un `PUT` en el método update del nuestro controller y simplemente lo declaramos de la siguiente manera:

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "DELETE"]
```